# Interactive Brokers API - How to disconnect an existing connection of IB Gateway and establish a new connection using Python?

Tags: python, interactive-brokers

I am testing Interactive Brokers Python API in a Hobby project. I am using Interactive Brokers Gateway (rather TWS). My project is a simple Django-based application. I can connect successfully and receive real-time data using the method `reqMktData()`. Everything is OK so far.

But when I refresh the page it shows **504 Not Connected**, although in IB Gateway it shows there is a running connection. To stop this, During a page reload I am trying to disconnect the previous connection using the **Eclient**  `disconnect()` method available in the API, but it can not disconnect the running connection.

Can anyone have any idea how can I disconnect a running connection in IB Gateway and start a new connection?

Comment: Seems like you've made multiple connections and are trying to disconnect the disconnected (inactive) one. Monitor active connection count when this happens.

Comment: Until I reload a page, there is only one connection. When I reload the page, I tried to disconnect the previous connection and establish a new one. So I don't think there have multiple connections and I tried to disconnect, that is already disconnected

Comment: 504 means your disconnecting a nonexisting connection. This error is not on IB side, review your code or post here. I use many sessions with connect/disconnect and it works without fault.

Comment: Here is the code of IB streaming I write: https://codeshare.io/2j3n1K

Comment: Here is the code that is used in the show page of my Apps: https://codeshare.io/5zZdpk

Answer (score 1):

Sample IB code. If you like to disconnect now, you just run: `app.disconnect()`

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
import threading
import time

tickers = ["NVDA", "SPY", "QQQ", "TQQQ", "SQQQ"]


class TradeApp(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
        self.lastPrice = {}

    def tickPrice(self, reqId, tickType, price, attrib):
        super().tickPrice(reqId, tickType, price, attrib)
        # print("TickPrice. TickerId:", reqId, "tickType:", tickType, "Price:", price)
        self.lastPrice[reqId] = price


def usTechStk(symbol, sec_type="STK", currency="USD", exchange="ISLAND"):
    contract = Contract()
    contract.symbol = symbol
    contract.secType = sec_type
    contract.currency = currency
    contract.exchange = exchange
    return contract


def streamSnapshotData(tickers):
    """stream tick level data"""
    for ticker in tickers:
        app.reqMktData(reqId=tickers.index(ticker),
                       contract=usTechStk(ticker),
                       genericTickList="",
                       snapshot=False,
                       regulatorySnapshot=False,
                       mktDataOptions=[])
        time.sleep(1)


def last_price(ticker):
    return app.lastPrice[tickers.index(ticker)]


def connection():
    app.run()


app = TradeApp()
# port 4002 for ib gateway paper trading/7497 for TWS paper trading
app.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=7497, clientId=23)

ConThread = threading.Thread(target=connection)
ConThread.start()

streamThread = threading.Thread(target=streamSnapshotData, args=(tickers,))
streamThread.start()
time.sleep(3)  # some lag added to ensure that streaming has started
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing my client Id seems to fix it for me. Maybe toggle back and forth between 2 of them?

Answer (score 0):

To disconnect from `TWS IBAPI` (python)

1. set attribute `ib.conn = None`
2. then call `ib.disconnect()` function,
3. then the callback function would `stop()` of `EWrapper` class